# I want to make a molecular block using particles

Tags: particles

I want to make a molecular block using particles like this one.

[image]

But I don't know how to put a texture to each particles seperately.

Or is particle not used in this block?

I want to say sorry to everyone who helped me.
I need to specify what I want to learn.

Comment: A particle system is not the ideal way to do this, no, but what the ideal way is depends on what you want to do with the block (and how you want to specify the color for each sphere-- you probably don't want to enter a color manually for 4096 spheres....)  A little more info on your end goals would help people answer your question better.

Answer (score 3):

Here an alternative solution with **Geometry Nodes** for the upcoming Blender **3.0** <sup>(alpha)</sup> and **Cycles** only. No particles involed and it doesn't work in Eevee :(

<sup>(Experimental! At the time of writing this answer Blender 3.0 is still an Alpha version and in development. Don't try this at home! Do not use it for production. It can mess up your blend file. Use at your own risk.)</sup>

The magic trick is to create the instance spheres at the vertex positions of the cube and use the vertex color to color them.

The *Point Instance* node is already available in Blender 2.93, but for the color data you need the new *Attribute Transfer* node of Blender 3.0.

[image: vertex painting]

**Step 1:** Subdivide your object (cube) if needed to create some vertices. For objects like a cone or torus add & apply the *Remesh* modifier to create more vertices. Try operation type `Block`.

Then switch to *Vertex Paint* mode and *Solid* view, choose *Vertex* color display in the *Viewport Shading* options so you can see what you paint. Stencil brush works in *Vertex Paint* and you can use images if you like.

**Step 2:** After this is done, create the sphere object. Keep it low-poly because it will be cloned many times. Then add a *Geometry Node* modifier to your object (cube, cone, torus, ...). Open the *Geometry Nodes* editor and create the node setup.
*Col* is the vertex color attribute. *Geo Color* is a custom attribute that is used to transfer the color. You can choose any name you want.

[image: gemetry node setup]

**Step 3:** Last but not least, create the material for the instance sphere. Here you use the *Attribute* node with the *Geo Color* attribute to get the color data.

[image: material setup]

Make sure you set viewport shading (<kbd>Z</kbd>) to *Rendered* and you use *Cycles*. The point instance color doesn't work in *Material Preview* mode (it's all black).

Answer (score 1):

I think the block was created with array modifiers, then the modifiers were applied so that you can give each object its own material.

Particles cannot have its own material for each particle. They got their material from the rendered object. But of course you could get such a result if the material is procedural.

And of course you could get the same result by manually copying spheres and use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to repeat the creation + move action you did.